# Azure Alerts - ScheduledQueryRule - Set Time Range in Query only

Tags: azure, alert, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-bicep

I am currently working on an Alert Rule in Log Analytics which is supposed to look back for 90 days, calculate a confidencelimit over that time and then compare today's value with the limit. If today's value exceeds the statistic, then the alert rule should fire.

Something like so (pseudo code):

```
let jobDurationTbl = latencyTbl
    | where name_s contains "latency_metrics" and TimeGenerated >= (now() - 90d)

let statisticsTbl = jobDurationTbl
    | summarize count(), upperConfidenceLimit = avg(jobDuration_ms) + 2 * stdev(jobDuration_ms) by serviceName_s

let alertTbl = latencyTbl
    | join kind=leftouter (jobDurationTbl) on serviceName_s
    | project
        serviceName_s,
        _ResourceId,
        TimeGenerated
    | join kind=leftouter (statisticsTbl) on serviceName_s
    | where jobDuration_ms > upperConfidenceLimit
    | where TimeGenerated == today;
```

Please note that I can not post the whole query here due to its length and complexity. The idea  is that we have a table `jobDurationTbl` which contains the length of jobs in ms (`jobDuration_ms`) for each service.  Then we create an `alertTbl` which should only return rows if the `jobDuration_ms` exceeds the `upperConfidenceLimit` calculated from the `statisticsTbl`

My problem is that the 90 days look back keeps getting overridden by the `windowSize` in the following line:  `TimeGenerated >= (now() - 90d)`. It is not clear what Log Analytics does, but I think it replaces the whole `(now() - 90d)` with the `windowSize`. I tried different syntaxes like:

```
YourTable
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(90d)
```

But still the time range gets overriden by the `windowSize`. Does someone know how the [Microsoft.Insights scheduledQueryRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) should be configured in such a case? I want to specify the windowing functionality solely in the query without the interference of any parameters. The evaluation period should be simply once a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution in the end. Thank you @Jahnavi you gave the missing clue with the binning logic. The final query with sample data looks as follows:

```
let Logs = datatable (TimeGenerated:datetime, ServiceName:string, jobDuration:int, _ResourceId:string ) [
   "1/4/2023, 2:33:36.000 PM", "Service A", 8945849, "/subscriptions/**************/resourcegroups/rg-******-prd-ingestion-landing/providers/microsoft.databricks/workspaces/dbw-******-prd-ingld",
   "12/4/2023, 2:33:36.000 PM", "Service A", 14, "/subscriptions/**************/resourcegroups/rg-******-prd-ingestion-landing/providers/microsoft.databricks/workspaces/dbw-******-prd-ingld",
   "12/5/2023, 3:33:36.000 PM", "Service B", 50, "/subscriptions/**************/resourcegroups/rg-******-prd-ingestion-landing/providers/microsoft.databricks/workspaces/dbw-******-prd-ingld",
   "12/5/2023, 3:33:36.000 PM", "Service B", 800, "/subscriptions/**************/resourcegroups/rg-******-prd-ingestion-landing/providers/microsoft.databricks/workspaces/dbw-******-prd-ingld",
   "12/6/2023, 1:33:36.000 PM", "Service C", 34982334, "/subscriptions/**************/resourcegroups/rg-******-prd-ingestion-landing/providers/microsoft.databricks/workspaces/dbw-******-ingld",
   "1/5/2024, 2:33:36.000 PM", "Service B", 45, "/subscriptions/**************/resourcegroups/rg-******-prd-ingestion-landing/providers/microsoft.databricks/workspaces/dbw-******-prd-ingld",
   "1/5/2024, 3:33:36.000 PM", "Service B", 5000, "/subscriptions/**************/resourcegroups/rg-******-prd-ingestion-landing/providers/microsoft.databricks/workspaces/dbw-******-prd-ingld"
] ;

let todaysRunTbl = Logs | where TimeGenerated >= startofday(now());
//todaysRunTbl

let statistiscsTbl = Logs
| where TimeGenerated <= startofday(now())
| where TimeGenerated > ago(90d)
| summarize upperConfidenceLimit = avg(jobDuration) + 3 * stdev(jobDuration) by bin(TimeGenerated, 90d), ServiceName
| project ServiceName, upperConfidenceLimit;


let alertTbl = todaysRunTbl | join kind=inner statistiscsTbl on ServiceName
| where jobDuration >= upperConfidenceLimit;
alertTbl
```

If today were the 1/5/2024, we would get the right result provided we have parameterized the alert correctly. The right result is the last row of the datatable. For reference, if we want to check every 15 minutes if there was an error in the last 1h, we would configure the alert as follows (bicep):

```
param windowSize = 'PT1H'
param evaluationFrequency = 'PT15M'

param timeAggregation = 'Count'

param operator = 'GreaterThanOrEqual'
param threshold = 1

param dimensions  = [
  {
    name: 'jobDuration'
    operator: 'Include'
    values: [ '*' ]
  }
  {
    name: 'upperConfidenceLimit'
    operator: 'Include'
    values: [ '*' ]
  }
]

param numberOfEvaluationPeriods = 1
param minFailingPeriodsToAlert = 1
```

We would get an alert for every row returned by the query.

Answer (score 1):

After a workaround on your issue, below are the results using [`Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/resource-manager-alerts-log?tabs=bicep) as well as KQL query.

Using `Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules` bicep resource provider, you can use below code to create a scheduled query rule.

```bash
param alert string = 'myjalert'
param location string 
param Description string = 'This is a metric alert'
param Severity int = 3
param isEnabled bool = true
param autoMitigate bool = true
param resourceId string = '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxx'
param query string = 'Perf | where ObjectName == \"Processor\" and CounterName == \"% Processor Time\"'
param metricMeasureColumn string = 'AggregatedValue'
param operator string = 'GreaterThan'
param threshold int = 0
param numberOfEvaluationPeriods int = 1
param minFailingPeriodsToAlert int = 1
param timeAggregation string = 'Average'
param windowSize string = 'PT5M'
param actionGroupId string = '/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/xx'

resource alert 'Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules@2021-08-01' = {
  name: alert
  location: location
  tags: {}
  properties: {
    description: Description
    severity: Severity
    enabled: isEnabled
    scopes: [
      resourceId
    ]
    evaluationFrequency: evaluationFrequency
    windowSize: windowSize
    criteria: {
      allOf: [
        {
          query: query
          metricMeasureColumn: metricMeasureColumn
          dimensions: []
          operator: operator
          threshold: threshold
          timeAggregation: timeAggregation
          failingPeriods: {
            numberOfEvaluationPeriods: numberOfEvaluationPeriods
            minFailingPeriodsToAlert: minFailingPeriodsToAlert
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    autoMitigate: autoMitigate
    actions: {
      actionGroups: [
         actionGroupId
      ]
      customProperties: {
        key1: 'xx'
        key2: 'xx'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Refer here for more relevant MS Doc sample [Bicep templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/resource-manager-alerts-log?tabs=bicep).

***Or***

Modify your `KQL` query by using [`avg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/avg-aggfunction#syntax) aggregated function to meet the expected requirement as shown.

```bash
YourTable 
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(90d) 
| summarize value = avg(<Metric>) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d) 
| project TimeGenerated, value
```

Comment: Thank you Jahnavi !  I see that my question had some gaps and I tried to clarify. To your answers, I am wondering in your first solution how do we have achieved a 90 day look back? And in solution 2 we are binning the values of each day with an average. That should work, But still condition is missing to compare today's value with the bin value of yesterday. Could we manage that over the parameters?

Comment: In the first one, you need to add your own query in place of query string and in the second one, what is the exact issue? Could you elaborate more on it. @DataBach

Comment: I updated my question. Is it more clear now? Thank you.

Comment: Can you try adding `extend yesterday = bin(datetime_add('day', -1, now()), 1d)`  this in the query and try? @DataBach